# i don't see any images on my site

Tags: image, hyperlink, xampp

In localhost (Xampp) I created a website folder, there are index.html, css, php and a folder with images. I wrote a link to the image I want to be in the index.html

> < body >
>   < img src="website/images/image.jpg"

but when I open this site in browser, there are no any images on my page. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the correct path would be

```
images/image.jpg
```

Because your file is already inside the website folder.